# RSSI (level values in dBm) using ScanResult.level

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-wireless

I'm trying to analyze the RSSI values obtained from different access points through continuous scan over a period of 2 minutes. 
There are sudden increase/decrease of 12dBm in consecutive scans,once in a while,for a particular access point.

Can someone elaborate on the drastic rise/fall in the RSSI value of a particular Access point for a consecutive scan(time difference of 100ms). There isn't much documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it's possible this is a software problem, it's at least as likely that you're seeing the impact of [*fading*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fading).

Comment: I am getting a range of values with a variance of 4dBm throughout. But in 2 or 3 results out of(6000) i am getting a sudden jump of 12dBm. If it were to be fading,the results should see a gradual rise/fall right?

Comment: The ScanResult.level is very volatile. For example, if someone passes between your phone and the router, there will be a significant change in the value.